# How can I change the colors (dropdown arrows, dropdown menus, etc.) of the main navigation bar of the WooThemes Resort Theme?

Tags: wordpress, woothemes

I seem to find the right code in layout.css, but when I add that to the style.css and change the colors nothing seems to happen, even after clearing cache. What is the recommended way to change the main nav bar colors for the Resort Theme?  http://www.notketchup.com  Thanks!!

Comment: add changes to layout.css:  #navigation ul.nav ul {... 239. line. layout.css is loaded after style.css, and all your changes are lost....

Answer (score 0):

Your WordPress theme's style.css needs a higher priority than the layout.css stylesheet.

In your theme's header.php, try moving the link to your style.css document to the line immediately before `</head>`

Failing that, try adding `!important` to your styles - e.g.

```
#myelement {
    color: #888 !important;
}
```